# How do I prevent .Run in Outlook from opening an Access instance twice?

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

In MS Outlook I have a button that calls a macro in MS Access. That macro opens a form and sets a text. Everytime if I push that button a new instance of Access is being opened. How do I prevent opening multiple instances of Access?

Outlook code:

```
'general declarations:
Public appAccess As Object


Sub OpenRecord()
    Dim Reference As String
    Dim docAccess

    Reference = 'teststring'

    Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    docAccess = appAccess.opencurrentdatabase("D:\Database\MSA_db.accdb")
    appAccess.Visible = True
    appAccess.Run "OpenInternalReference", Reference
End Sub
```

Access Code:

```
Public Sub OpenInternalReference(MailReference As String)
    Dim stDocName As String
    Dim stLinkCriteria As String

    stDocName = "browse"
    DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria

    Forms("Browse").prefilter.SetFocus
    Forms("Browse").prefilter.Text = MailReference
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not the `.Run` method, it is your `Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")` since it always creates a new instance of access.

This code tries to get an Access Application that is already opened and creates a new if none is found:

```
Dim appAccess As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set appAccess = GetObject(Class:="Access.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

If appAccess Is Nothing Then
    Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
End If
```

Comment: Only thing I had to add was an `On Error Resume Next` above the `opencurrentdatabase` command.

Comment: @Jellema If you added On Error Resume Next then you also had to add On Error Goto 0. Otherwise we have to charge an error in Peer Review.

Comment: @niton: ok, I will use that